# Need help changing x axis intervals on sns.lmplot

Tags: python, seaborn

As you can see from the picture below, some of the data is cut off on the end. Does anyone know how to fix that? Also I want the intervals for weeks on the x axis to be (1,2,3...13) for weeks 1-13. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please avoid posting images and include your code instead, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide the data, I used an example below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(111)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Week':np.tile(np.arange(1,15),2),
                  'Score':np.random.uniform(np.repeat([0,1],14),
                                            np.repeat([1,2],14),28),
                   'Win':np.repeat(['0','1'],14)
                  })
```

sns.lmplot returns a FacetGrid so you can set the axis ticks like this:

```
g = sns.lmplot(data=df,x='Week',y='Score',hue='Win')
g.set(xlim = (0.5,14.5))
g.set(xticks=range(14))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. Much apprecieated